# Why do I need to resolve my change again when I do another rebase

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, rebase, remote-branch

I have two branches, `master` and `my-work-branch`

Other people will push changes to `master`, so I need to keep `my-work-branch` synced with `master` so that I also get other people`s changes

I tried to rebase from `my-work-branch` against `master` branch often with the following command

```
git rebase origin/master
```

I did that two days ago, so git log in `my-work-branch` is something like this:

```
merge change from master
my change a
my change b
my change c
...
latest change from master two days ago
```

Today I ran the same rebase command again, (during the two days, I do not have any changes on `my-work-branch`, all I do is try to get new changes from `master`)

However, I noticed that git applies my changes (`a, b, c ...` ) twice (I can see it in the `git log`), and also it caused conflicts, so I need to resolve the conflicts.

Does anyone know why this would happen? 
Is `git rebase` the wrong way to keep `my-work-branch` in sync with `master` branch?

Comment: I think you want git pull instead of git rebase

Comment: @Jonathan, git pull will pull from my remote branch, do you mean i specify the origin to pull from master?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101994/git-pull-from-master-into-the-development-branch

Comment: @Jonathan, i saw that, but that merge changes base on time line. but i think i got it now. i should do "git pull --rebase origin master", then it will bring my change on top of change from master

Answer (score 0):

Git rebase is perfectly OK to keep branches in sync, in fact some people (like me) prefer it over the push/merge technique as the way to keep more straight history. But you have to get used to this command.

I assume you regularly do `git fetch` to keep your `origin/master` in sync with the other people's changes.

It is normal to get conflicts on repeated rebases in such case because there could have been new changes upstream (`origin/master`) that have caused it.

I am not sure why do you see same commits twice, maybe because you are in incomplete rebase?

In order to check what is happening, you could `git rebase abort` to restore the state before you started the rebase, and do `git rebase -i origin/master` - it would show you the commits picked to be put on top of the `origin/master`. If there is more than you expect - something is wrong with your branch state.

You may also use combination of `git log <my branch> --not origin/master` and `git log origin/master --not <my branch>` to easily see commits that are present upstream but not in your branch and vice versa.